# Parsing nested xml via python giving empty list instead of tag values

Tags: python, xml, soap, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to fetch all Id tags values from the below xml (SOAP API):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <infasoapns:Body xmlns:eAPI="http://api.ppdi.com/1.1/Site" xmlns:infasoapns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:infawsdlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <eAPI:getSiteResponse>
         <eAPI:SITE>
            <eAPI:Id>CTMSR_1-1036KJ</eAPI:Id>
            <eAPI:Sponsor>Ell Inc</eAPI:Sponsor>
            <eAPI:CRO>PDP</eAPI:CRO>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Number>EL184-308</eAPI:Protocol_Number>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Id>CTMSR_1-LCXB0</eAPI:Protocol_Id>
        </eAPI:SITE>
        <eAPI:SITE>
            <eAPI:Id>CTMSR_1-1036SM</eAPI:Id>
            <eAPI:Sponsor>Ell Inc</eAPI:Sponsor>
            <eAPI:CRO>PDP</eAPI:CRO>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Number>EL184-308</eAPI:Protocol_Number>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Id>CTMSR_1-LCXB0</eAPI:Protocol_Id>
        </eAPI:SITE>
        <eAPI:SITE>
            <eAPI:Id>CTMSR_1-1036SM</eAPI:Id>
            <eAPI:Sponsor>Ell Inc</eAPI:Sponsor>
            <eAPI:CRO>PDP</eAPI:CRO>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Number>EL184-308</eAPI:Protocol_Number>
            <eAPI:Protocol_Id>CTMSR_1-LCXB0</eAPI:Protocol_Id>
        </eAPI:SITE>
      </eAPI:getSiteResponse>
   </infasoapns:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code I wrote is below that gave empty list in the output

1. when I ran tree.findall('.//Id'), it gave output: []
2. when I ran print(tree.find('Id')), it gave output: None
3. when I ran tree.find('Id').text, it gave output:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 tree.find('Id').text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Code:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
>>> file_path = 'C:\\Users\\dshukla\\Desktop\\docs\\PPD project\\Response\\WS_SITES_1.1_RES'
>>> tree = ElementTree.parse(file_path)
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> print(root)
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x00000238F6BFCD10>
>>> tree.findall('.//Id')
[]
>>> tree.find('Id')
>>> print(tree.find('Id'))
None
>>> tree.find('Id').text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
>>>
```

**Why am I getting empty list/None type error ? how can I fetch values of ID tags from this xml file ? **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse SOAP XML with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250626/how-to-parse-soap-xml-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass namespaces to `findall()`. There are four namespace in your file.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
file_path = 'yourfile.xml'  # change to your file path

tree = ElementTree.parse(file_path)

root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {"soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
              "eAPI": "http://api.ppdi.com/1.1/Site",
              "infasoapns": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
              "infawsdlns": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"}

names = root.findall('*/eAPI:getSiteResponse/eAPI:SITE/eAPI:Id', namespaces)  # pass namespaces like this

for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

And this is the result:

```
CTMSR_1-1036KJ
CTMSR_1-1036SM
CTMSR_1-1036SM
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. My code worked now by including your suggested namespaces. Greatly appreciate all your inputs.